# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(".fancybox").fancybox()')

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Working on a new version of my site but can't get fancy box to load properly:

http://www.taintmovie.com/storecartloom2/

I checked for duplicate calls to jquery, but did not see any.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Digging a little bit more into the issue, is not the packed version of the fancybox.js file that is broken as previously suggested (I compared the file with the fancybox website and they matched.)

There are three things you have to fix in your website in order to get rid of the error and make fancybox to work properly:

1). Close your `<head>` tag (currently there is not `</head>` closing tag)

2). You said you checked for jQuery duplicates BUT you are loading this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="cljs" src="https://taintmovie.cartloom.com/cart/cl?dr=1&ol=1"></script>
```

[LINK HERE](https://taintmovie.cartloom.com/cart/cl?dr=1&ol=1), which includes jQuery v1.4.2 so it's conflicting with v1.7.2 already loaded.

This is actually the reason of this error:

```
Error: TypeError: $(".fancybox").fancybox is not a function
Source File: http://www.taintmovie.com/storecartloom2/
Line: 40
```

... you may want to edit that file and strip out the jQuery part.

3). You are binding fancybox to the selector `.fancybox` like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

...however your html looks like:

```
<a class="fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bHEEdUQCNsM?autoplay=1"><img src="images/pantheonblack300.png"></a>
```

you actually need to set the class `fancybox` besides the `fancybox.iframe` class like:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bHEEdUQCNsM?autoplay=1"><img src="images/pantheonblack300.png"></a>
```

... otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I found the solution to the Cartloom jQuery issue by adding "nojq=1" to the view cart script from cartloom: http://forums.realmacsoftware.com/discussion/43767/joe-workman-lightbox-and-cartloom-2-0-script-conflict-updated

Comment: @user1539382 : you found the solution for the point number 2, but I gave you 1 and 3

Comment: I had the exact same problem. The resolving the jQuery conflict fixed it. I checked using firebug to see which scripts are loaded and found out that the gallery was loading jQuery 1.4.3 and I loaded 1.4.2. Got rid of my jQuery import and voila. THANKS !!! Would have wasted a lot of time on it.

Answer (score 0):

Messing about with firebug it looks like the packed version of the fancybox.js is broken. I changed the source in the developer console to the unpacked version and it ran properly.

Comment: Curiously I compared http://www.taintmovie.com/storecartloom2/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.6 with http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.6 and both files match.

Comment: Yeah. It's probably the packer that the author of fancybox is using. I remember having problems with it the other week. I would just switch to the minified version if I were you.

Comment: I recall a similar issue and the workaround was to force the ftp software to transfer the files as binary (default was ASCII)

Comment: ?? If you are sending a javascript file the mimetype should be text/javascript and the character set should be utf-8. It's the packed file. I checked it.