# Issue in using Fancybox

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm new to use fancybox.
i added correct path to fancybox source files and i tried in both chrome and firefox, both console returns me error

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined [Break On This Error]
>
> }(window, document, jQuery));
>
> jquery...ybox.js (line 2020) TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a
>   function [Break On This Error]
>
> 'type'          : 'iframe'

and my code is

>

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
>       $("#iframe").fancybox({
>     'width'         : '75%',
>     'height'        : '75%',
>     'autoScale'     : false,
>     'transitionIn'  : 'none',
>     'transitionOut' : 'none',
>     'type'          : 'iframe' });    });

<a id="iframe" href="/cms/new.php">Submit</a>
```

can any one figure out my issue and give me solutions?

Comment: you sure you are using fancybox 2 (you are using API options for v1.3.4)? what version of jQuery? if you look at your source code and click on the links to jQuery and fancybox js files: can you see the code? got a link?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not linking to the appropriate fancybox source file(s).
Make sure to include these **exactly once** in your head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570952/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-fancybox-fancybox) for more information.

Comment: What is self-explanatory to you might be very difficult to someone else.  If OP is a new coder and doesn't understand that jquery needs to be included, it could be confusing.  Help without condescension.

Comment: I never meant to sound condescending, and I apologize to OP if he was insulted in any way. I edited my answer. :)